# How to configure my route.config file in asp.net to achieve a URL as described below?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a controller called product and within that controller I have an `ActionResult` called `ProductDetails`. Mentioned `ActionResult` passes a specif product value to the view and then I get an `URL` as below:

```
https://localhost:44304/Product/ProductDetails?ProductID=1
```

What I want is that I would like to replace the last part which is `?ProductID=1` to the product name itself like below:

```
https://localhost:44304/Product/ProductDetails?LamborghiniVeyron
```

Any idea, help please.

**EDIT:**

Here is the current route configuration.

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(null, "Page{page}",
            new
            {
                controller = "Product",
                action = "List",
                category =
                    (string)null
            },
            new { page = @"\d+" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(null,
            "{category}",
            new { controller = "Product", action = "List", page = 1 }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(null,
            "{category}/Page{page}",
            new { controller = "Product", action = "List" },
            new { page = @"\d+" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");

            routes.MapRoute(
            "Images",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",
            new { controller = "Product", action = "GetMainPicture", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "mynamespace.Controllers" }
        );


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tricky; `?LamborghiniVeyron` would be a parameter name. Easier to do is something like `?name=LamborghiniVeyron`

Comment: ps: could you post the current route configuration?

Comment: Please see updated question for the route configuration. @Stefan

Answer (score 1):

You have some options here:

First of all let us assume the following url signature:

```
https://localhost:44304/Product/ProductDetails/LamborghiniVeyron
//                         |           |                |
//                    controller     action            id
```

Note that I omitted the `?` part and putted the name as id.

This correspons with your default route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                                            id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

My guess is (haven't done this in a while ;-)) that when you define an action in your controller like below, that it will work.

```
public ProductController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult ProductDetails(string id) //be advised: string!
     {
          //id contains LamborghiniVeyron
          //you can use this in your query
          return View();
     }
}
```

How it works: the route config defines your route, in which a controller, action and id is defined. If your parameter is called `id` the modelbinder will bind to this parameter, even if you are using a name.

Alternatively you could redefine your route config to rename the parameter to `name` or something similar. Beware, that can lead to some nasty little bugs.